# Force user to access the site using https:// ONLY

Tags: php, regex

I want to force to user to access my site using https:// so that I'm using following php code and .htaccess file.

**php code:**

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on') {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
        header(sprintf(
            'Location: https://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        ));
        exit();
    }
}
```

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For example my site url name is : **www.example.com**. If change the url to http:// from https:// it's successfully redirect to https:// **but** if I change the url to http://www.example.com. then it's not going to https://. It's accepting http://.

**Note: I've paid version of https://**

I want that user can't access my site WITHOUT HTTPS:// anymore. HOW CAN I DO THIS ?

Comment: please go here, this question have answe before. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/should-we-force-user-to-https-on-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Apache, the easiest way is to use .htaccess to automatically redirect http access to https. Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Save the above code in your existing .htaccess file in your root folder. If you do not have an .htaccess file, you can save the above as a plain text file and save it with the name .htaccess. Note the leading '.' in the file name. It is important. Upload that file to your root directory.